# PostgreSQL 9.3 - ELEMENT IS CONTAINED BY vs. BETWEEN

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a large (30M Rows) simple table...

```
CREATE TABLE "Foo"."Bar" (
    "BarID" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "DateTime" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "Bar" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

... a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Foo"."Bar"("DateTime");
```

... and a simple question:

**What `"BarID"` values have a `"DateTime"` value in the first hour of 2015?**

---

So I made this query #1:

```
SELECT
    "Bar"."BarID"
FROM
    "Foo"."Bar"
WHERE
    "Bar"."DateTime" <@ TSRANGE('2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 01:00:00');
```

... and this query #2:

```
SELECT
    "Bar"."BarID"
FROM
    "Foo"."Bar"
WHERE
    "Bar"."DateTime" BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 01:00:00';
```

### Results

Query #1 runs in 60 seconds with a sequence scan.

Query #2 runs in 0.02 seconds with an index scan.

I tried making another index `USING GiST` with no improvement.

**What gives?**

Comment: My guess is `BETWEEN` is [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and `TSRANGE()` is not.

Answer (score 5):

Range expressions are sargable. You just need an index that a range expression can use. You have a B-tree index and a GiST index on a column of type "timestamp". A timestamp range expression can't take advantage of either of those indexes.

Create a GiST index on a timestamp range expression, and update the statistics.

```
create index on "Foo"."Bar" 
using gist(tsrange("DateTime"::timestamp, "DateTime"::timestamp, '[]'));

analyze "Foo"."Bar";
```

Your "DateTime" column represents a point in time, so the timestamp range expression should have inclusive lower *and* upper bounds (`'[]'`).

Rewrite the WHERE clause to use the same expression.

```
explain analyze
select "BarID"
from "Foo"."Bar"
where tsrange("DateTime"::timestamp, "DateTime"::timestamp, '[]') <@ tsrange('2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 01:00:00');
```

That query can use the index, and it runs here in about half a millisecond on a table of around a million rows.

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on "Bar"  (cost=10.19..859.53 rows=246 width=8) (actual time=0.195..0.551 rows=219 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (tsrange("DateTime", "DateTime", '[]'::text) <@ '["2015-01-01 00:00:00","2015-01-01 01:00:00")'::tsrange)"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Bar_tsrange_idx"  (cost=0.00..10.13 rows=246 width=0) (actual time=0.160..0.160 rows=219 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (tsrange("DateTime", "DateTime", '[]'::text) <@ '["2015-01-01 00:00:00","2015-01-01 01:00:00")'::tsrange)"
"Total runtime: 0.589 ms"
```